# Updating Excel 2003/ 2007 Cell value from C#

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net, oledb

I have an Excel sheet with no column names.

I want to update values of individual cells without using a WHERE condition.
For example Cell A1 is empty and I would like to insert string value "Foo" into it. Below is what I have tried but its not working.

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
string sql = null;
var myConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\\Users\\MAX\\Desktop\\test.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
myConnection.Open();
myCommand.Connection = myConnection;

sql = "UPDATE Sheet1 SET A1='Foo'";
myCommand.CommandText = sql;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
myConnection.Close();
```

Comment: I found OleDb with Excel to be very quirky.  I know your title mentions Excel 2003, but if you can limit yourself to only .xlsx files, the open source EPPlus library is *far* easier to use than OleDb.

Comment: Hi  Eric J, thanks for replying. Unfortunately I have to use excel 2003.

Comment: Tell me if the answer help you.

Comment: I know that this is not an answer, however, you should consider update data on Excel files using data providers only if your data structure is similar to a database table, with rows and columns. Obviously, the main advantage of this approach is to avoid use interop. Even though, sounds like a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this.

```
   sql = "UPDATE [Sheet1$A1:A1]  SET F1='FOO'";
```

Here is another **[question](http://forums.asp.net/t/1214491.aspx?How%20to%20update%20single%20cell%20of%20excel%20sheet%20using%20oledb%20connection%20)**, which you can use if it is not clear enough.